# Read Parquet file using Apache Beam Java SDK without providing schema

Tags: java, apache-beam, apache-beam-io

It seems that the `org.apache.beam.sdk.io.parquet.ParquetIO.readFiles` method requires a schema to be passed in.

- Is there a way to avoid the need to pass in the schema?
- Isn't the schema included in the Parquet file?
- What if I am trying to read multiple Parquet files with different schema?

Answer (score 0):

Please find my response inline

- Is there a way to avoid the need to pass in the schema?
  Currently there is no mechanism to avoid passing schema of the parquet files
- Isn't the schema included in the Parquet file?
  Yes that is correct, the metadata in the header as the schema definition of the file. Please refer to [BEAM-8344](https://github.com/apache/beam/pull/9721) which is an Open Feature request to support infer schema
- What if I am trying to read multiple Parquet files with different schema?
  You can do something as below, wherein you can pass file patterns and paths and specify different schemas.

```
  PCollection<FileIO.ReadableFile> files = pipeline
    .apply(FileIO.match().filepattern(options.getInputFilepattern())
    .apply(FileIO.readMatches());

  PCollection<GenericRecord> output = files.apply(ParquetIO.readFiles(SCHEMA));
```

Comment: It would be better to read **file patterns and schema** pairs to read multiple parquet files with different schemas to avoid reading all the files for each schema.